# Failed asserting for Mockup object

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I have problem with mocking object in PHPUnit:

```
class FootballTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Football
     */
    protected $object;

    /**
     * Sets up the fixture, for example, opens a network connection.
     * This method is called before a test is executed.
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->siteName = 'football';
        $this->footballAPIMock = $this->getMock('FootballAPI');
        $this->object = new Football($this->siteName,$this->footballAPIMock);
    }

    /**
     * Tears down the fixture, for example, closes a network connection.
     * This method is called after a test is executed.
     */
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        $this->object = null;
    }


    public function testGetByTeamOutrights()
    {
        $markets = 5;
        $this->footballAPIMock->expects($this->any())
                             ->method('getByTeamOutrights')
                             ->with($this->equalTo(5))
                             ->will($this->returnValue(5));

        $this->assertNull($this->object->getByTeamOutrights(5));

    }
}
```

And I'm getting Fail asserting that Football Object

PHPUnit version 3.6.12

Comment: I'm not sure what are you expecting. What "getByTeamOutrights" method from Football class returns? Is this method returns sth like: $this->footballAPI->getByTeamOutrights() ? If so, then it should return 5, not null.. Please post more info about "getByTeamOutrights" method from Football class

Comment: Sorry for mess .. Everything is returning OK and everything is working  like suppose to work

Comment: @MarceliJanowski If that means you've solved your problem, and there is no question here anymore, you should see a delete link to get rid of the question. You might even get a badge for being a Tidy Citizen :-)